# problem on sending and receiving e-mail after changing the the server

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, windows-server-2008-r2

I am having problem sending and receiving e-mail after changing the server.
I put my website on a windows server 2008 R2. I updated the DNS setting of my domain and it works fine but now I have problems on receiving and sending e-mail **to/from e-mail addresses which are all hosted inside same server** address. I tried other e-mail addresses and they worked fine.

So what could be the problem here? is it related to my new server or should I dig into the server which hosted the e-mail addresses?

Comment: What's the error in the bounced messages?

Comment: @TiZon I am not getting any error. It sends the message but it never receives it. It didn't go to junk box as well.

Comment: Did you update the MX entries in DNS? Is the server joined to a domain which has the same name as your website? Where are you trying to send/receive mail from (A client, a script, the command line?)? What do you mean you tried other e-mail addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might start by going through the logs of the receiving email server to see if any of the email delivery attempts even made it to the server and then working your way back to the actual web script/code that sends the email (assuming that is the problem based on your description).

Answer (score 0):

If you updated the MX record, you also need to call your ISP and have them update the PTR record that corresponds to the A record listed in your MX record. Otherwise, most accepting domains will filter you as SPAM.

Comment: Psst!  Xe's sending mail to mailboxes that are hosted locally.  (It's in boldface in the question.)  SMTP, and the various daft shenanighans that people play with it, aren't necessarily even a part of the picture _at all_.